# GraphQL filtering on an embedded ID

Tags: graphql

I have a custom schema I need to work with, here's a slightly abbreviated version:

```
schema {
  query: Query
}

type Query {
  environment(locale: LocaleEnum!): Environment
}

type Environment {
  articles(
    offset: Int = 0
    limit: Int = 20
  ): ArticleConnection!
}

type ArticleConnection {
  total: Int!
  items: [Article!]
}

type Article {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
}
```

I was able to get a list of article IDs by running

```
query {
  environment(locale: EN) {
    articles {
      total,
      items {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to filter on the article id? Like, I just want a single, specific article.

Comment: Your schema is what determines what is and isn't possible, so it's not quite clear what you're asking here. Are you asking if it's possible to do that using the existing schema or are you asking how to add that functionality to your schema?

Comment: I am asking whether it's possible using the existing schema. I have never used GraphQL before today. Is there a feature where a filter can be written against a piece of already defined data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clients can manipulate the "shape" of a GraphQL service's response in one of three ways:

- By providing different [selection sets](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Selection-Sets) (i.e. choosing different fields to query)
- By utilizing [inline fragments](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Inline-Fragments), which allow a specific selection set to be applied to a field based on the actual type of the field at runtime
- By utilizing the `@skip` and `@include` [directives](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec--skip) to explicitly exclude or include an individual field from the selection set.

Outside of the above, GraphQL does not provide any built-in mechanisms for filtering, sorting, pagination or other arbitrary transformations of the response. These features are service-specific and have to implemented as part of your schema, which represents the collective abilities of your service.

For example, you might add another field to your `Environment` type like:

```
type Environment {
  article(
    id: ID!
  ): Article
}
```

If you're developing a client that uses an existing schema, there's not much you can do if the schema doesn't expose the functionality you need.